# Rails bundle failing while installing atomic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm just getting into ruby on rails, And I'm setting it up on a second windows computer.

I've used the most recent 'railsinstaller' using rails: 4.0.0 and ruby: 2.0.0p195

when I run `rails new <project name>` Rails creates the project but fails on the bundle step with the following error.

```
Installing atomic (1.1.14)
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
creating Makefile


Gem files will remain installed in D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/atomic-1.1.14 for inspection.
Results logged to D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/atomic-1.1.14/ext/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing atomic (1.1.14), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install atomic -v '1.1.14'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I've tried a few things I've found on google such as updating gem and ruby but none of that worked... I'm too new to rails to figure this out myself, does anyone know what might be the problem?

***EDIT***

the outcome of `gem install atomic -v '1.1.14'`

```
D:\Programming\Ruby>gem install atomic -v '1.1.14'
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ConEmu blocks ANSICON injection
The system cannot find the file D:\ansicon\ansicon-master\ansicon.exe.
ERROR:  Error installing atomic:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
creating Makefile


Gem files will remain installed in D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/atomic-1.1.14 for inspection.
Results logged to D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/atomic-1.1.14/ext/gem_make.out
```

Thanks,
Peter McKinney

Comment: run `gem install atomic -v '1.1.14'` and post the output

Comment: @TRENT, added in the edit

Comment: do you have `ansicon.exe.` installed?

Comment: yeah, I've also no idea why that's coming up, ansicon.exe is in that path and was working fine for cucumber in a previous install